# Python how to make a list out of all the indexes with a certain value from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, indexing

```
my_list = ["1", "2", "X", "2", "4", "6", "X"]

def function1(arg1):
    if arg1 == "Y": 
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I need to create a new list  with all the index positions of list_ that have the value "X" and are True through function1.

I know the function is illogical, I simplified everything for the purpose of the question.
Thanks!

Comment: With your `function1` nothing that has a value `X` will be `True`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? This seems a bit broad, have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

> You want to get all the indexes of elements that match a certain value in an array

This list comprehension should do it:

```
my_list = ["1", "2", "X", "2", "4", "6", "X"]

my_new_list = [x for x in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[x] == "X"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can build a list while iterating and using if to check conditions.

```
new_list = [i for i, arg in enumerate(my_list) if arg == 'X' and function1(arg)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, (there is probably a better way)

```
# creating a list of the indexes in my_list with "X" values:
list1 = [n for n, i in enumerate(my_list) if i == "X"]

# creating a list of the indexes of list1 which are True in function1
list2 = [n for n, i in enumerate(list1) if function1(i)]

# creating the final list with the original indexes from my_list of the "X" values that are True from function1
list3 = [list1[i] for i in list2]
```